# Send select row data to classic asp, javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp-classic

Here is what I have so far:

```
$("#job_list tr").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0kk0yupb/2/

How do I post the selected row data (id) to test.asp page?

Comment: Do you want to send row by row (send one id per click), or more selected rows in same time (on select box change)? Anyway, http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: i want it so test.asp can catch all the row that was selected. (it can be 1 row or 10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `disabled` attribute to eliminate inputs that do not have parent with `.selected` class before the form submission.

Based on your fiddle, have a look at this : http://jsfiddle.net/60utpttd/

Comment: a quick question for you tho, what to do so user cant select the first row?

Comment: i figured. do this: $("#job_list tr:not(:first)").click(function()